Modified Rodrigues parameters (MRP) operations
Please help to find useful operations on MRPs such as multiplication, rotation of vector, conversion to matrix  etc.
Do exists faster implicit conversion without conversion to quaternions? All my versions are comparable performance with conversion to/from quaternions. Note that conversion mrp2quat takes 12 FLOPS, and back quat2mrp 4 FLOPS (it is very fast).
